# How can I combine Month Column and Year Column in Excel into Month-Year so that Google Data Studio / Looker Studio can detect it as Date?

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, excel-formula, looker-studio

I Have data that look like this:

Column A : Year
2020
2020
2020
2021
2021
2021
etc

Column B : Month
1
2
3
4
5
6
etc

How can I combine Month Column and Year Column in Excel into Month-Year so that Google Data Studio / Looker Studio can detect it as Date???

Because when I use this format in Google Data Studio, "Year" column doesn't support date format, while Month column can be detected in GDS. What is the proper date format for Google Data Studio?? Do I have to change the date format in Google Data Studio or change it in Excel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may create n' use a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6299685) within the dash to create a date field based on two existing dimensions of `Year` & `Month_Number`*

```js
PARSE_DATE("%F",CONCAT(Year,"-",Month,"-",1))
```

[image]